How to properly read battery cells voltage from a battery pack?
I have a battery pack that has 16 cells, maximum voltage is 67.2V. I need to read out the voltage of each cell with a high precision, preferably 1 mV using a built-in 12 bit ADC of STM32F103.
I think that to get high precision I need to measure each cell separately rather than measure the cell voltage referenced to the battery pack ground.
To accomplish that I guess I need an isolated power supply for the MCU and some type of analog switches to connect each cell to the ADC input? Would a differential ADC be of a benefit here? Any pointers are helpful. Thanks!

Can you tell us why you need this precise voltages. Do you know that battery voltage is not a good indicator of battery charge?

You would do much better to use an approriate battery monitor IC, than over complicating the whole STM32 environment.

Yes I know that it's not a good indicator of battery charge level and I'm aware of battery monitor ICs, however for this particular project I cannot use them.

If this is a one-off, it might make sense to: Design a single cell monitor, confirm it works to your liking, add isolation for power and data, and then just build 16 of them. If you don't mind powering from the cell the isolation might even be fairly simple.
